# JOGL - Multiple textures

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

In my project im looking to use a few textures for different objects.

At the minute I have the following code:

```
private Texture[] textures = new Texture[1];
private int texture1 = 0; // Which Filter To Use
private String textureFilename = "src/data/image.jpg";
```

And also `textures[texture1].bind(gl);` to bind it to the object, at the minute the texture is being bound to every object, which isnt what I want.

Im assuming theres a way to include a list of textures which can then be bound to each object? Just wondering how to do this, ive tried copying and editing the above code but its giving me errors so im guessing im doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`private Texture[] textures = new Texture[1+more];`
`//private int texture1 = 0; // Which Filter To Use`
`private String textureFilename[1+more] = "src/data/image.jpg";`

`File textureFile = new File(textFile);`
`textures[any] = TextureIO.newTexture(textureFilename[any], true);`

`// draw`
`gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);`
`texture[Index].bind();`
`texture[Index].enable();`
`...